# How to solve `node `Installation' lacks menu item for XXX' in installing TRAMP for emacs?

Tags: emacs, tramp

I tried to install TRAMP2.4.1 for my emacs (26.1).
I encountered this problem when I make

make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
makeinfo --no-warn --no-split -D  installchapter --footnote-style=end -o ../info/tramp tramp.texi
./trampinst.texi:9: node`Installation' lacks menu item for `System Requirements' despite being its Up target
./trampinst.texi:9: node`Installation' lacks menu item for `Basic Installation' despite being its Up target
./trampinst.texi:9: node`Installation' lacks menu item for `Installation parameters' despite being its Up target
./trampinst.texi:9: node`Installation' lacks menu item for `Testing' despite being its Up target
./trampinst.texi:9: node`Installation' lacks menu item for `Load paths' despite being its Up target
make[1]: *** [../info/tramp] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2

How to solve this?

Comment: Since Emacs 22.1, tramp has been included in Emacs. There's no need to install it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bug. Either use the tramp that comes with Emacs 26.1, or if you have to have the bleeding edge, get it from its git repo. (See [Obtaining Tramp](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Obtaining-TRAMP).)

Comment: Thanks for the help. It turns out that after Emacs 22.1, tramp has been included in Emacs. There's no need to install it.